# How do I stop timer reset after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, time, hide, counter

I am creating a few pages for academic purposes and I want to hide the "Next" button for a certain amount of seconds. The problem is that once the page gets refreshed, the timer starts all over. I want it to continue after the page is refreshed and I want to improve the code that is already written rather than see a new solution.

```
<strong>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-primary next-button" type="submit" value="Next"/>
    <script>
        var showButton = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-large btn-primary next-button")[0];
        var counter = 5;
        var newElement = document.createElement("p");
        newElement.innerHTML = "You can proceed to the subsequent page in " + counter + " seconds.";
        var interval;
        showButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, showButton);
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            counter--;
            if(counter < 0) {
                newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(showButton, newElement);
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                newElement.innerHTML = "You can proceed to the subsequent page in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</strong>
```

I do understand the idea behind the localStorage but where exactly do I need to insert it? I am trying to insert it beside "var counter" but it does not do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `localStorage` or `cookies` to store data and use even after page reload.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

**UPDATE**

After updated question, here is how you need to store and get `counter` variable from `localStorage`

when you declared counter variable:

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");
counter = counter ? counter : 5 ;  // if in store then that value otherwise 5 as default
```

You can detect page reload/refresh using javascript `onbeforeunload` event and same time store the counter value for next use.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
 };
```

**UPDATE-2**

Here is a working fiddle that you can use:

https://jsfiddle.net/wdar3yuq/

Comment: Thanks for the help but I cannot manage to do it. I have changed "var counter = 5;" to "var counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");" and have added a line below "counter = counter ? counter : 5;". In the newElement.innerHTML, instead of "counter", I have added localStorage.setItem("counter", counter): both in function and where the variable is set. Lastly, instead of "interval = setInterval(function()..." I have written "window.onbeforeunload.interval = setInterval(function()...". Not sure if that is exactly what you have suggested because I do not know programming at all.

Comment: @viiivi  can you create a fiddle or plunker ? we can then dig into your real code with the changes .

Comment: what is "window.onbeforeunload.interval" ?? you just need same syntax that I have given . Event is a separate entity and need not to mix with interval.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry for the confusion. These are the changes I have done: https://jsfiddle.net/1e4y0936/

Comment: @viiivi No problem, I have updated my answer with a working fiddle. Changes in your fiddle (1) corrected usage of `counter` variable (2) correct wrong method `window.onbeforeunload.interval` (3) modified storage key name to avoid conflict with your browser (That holds a prior storage key) (4) Added removestorage when counter reaches 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works just as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client-sided. It will **reset** on **reload** or any other thing.

A simple solution to your problem might be HTML5 `storage`, or `session storage`

Example :

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

HTML web storage provides two objects for storing data on the client:

1. `window.localStorage` - stores data with no expiration date
2. `window.sessionStorage` - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

**The localStorage Object**

The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

More Documentation about LocalStorage [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: I get the whole idea but I am clueless where exactly I should add the localStorage in my code. Tried adding it everywhere and it results in either the timer stopping completely or resetting after the refresh.